# How to retrieve the string from txt file in android studio?

Tags: android, android-volley

In android, I am able to read a string from text file and print it out by Toast but I am failing to store it in a variable for further process

Android code:

```
try {
        FileInputStream fileIn=openFileInput("mytextfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader InputRead= new InputStreamReader(fileIn);
        char[] inputBuffer= new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s = String.valueOf(inputBuffer[0]);
        int charRead;
        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0) {

            String readstring=String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
            s +=readstring;
        }
        InputRead.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String a = s;
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://"+a+"/try.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("encoded_string", encoded_string);
                map.put("image_name","IMG_Hello.jpg");
                return map;
            }
        };
```

`String a` should contain the string that store in **mytextfile.txt**

Can anyone give me any ideas? Because currently in the above code the `String a` is failing to store the text from **mytextfile.txt**

Comment: yes, sorry for my worst english

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` Please tell which text the user sees.

Comment: `String a = s;` That is not needed. You can directly use s.

Comment: If the text is in s then the text should be in a too. What else?

Comment: in txt file, it contain 127.168.43.184, so it will show the content by toast, the toast is working well, just I want to store in variable"a" so that I can further process the variable "a" and put it in the url below

Comment: `I am able to read a string from text file and print it out by Toast`. Ok so s contains the text. `in the above code the String a is failing to store the text from mytextfile.txt` Well impossible. Content of a should be equal to s.

Comment: String a does not contain the content in txt file, how to store it in variable "a"?

Comment: Impossible. Just make another Toast to display a.

Comment: the toast i just want to show it whether the script can read or not, but actually my purpose is store the content in variable a which is string a

Comment: Yes. I know. Ok. Does not matter. But contents of a is equal to that of s. Toast it!

Comment: but the link cannot connect to the server which mean the ip address actually is the content in txt

Comment: ???? Now did you Toast a? Please do and tell what you see!

Comment: `String s = String.valueOf(inputBuffer[0]);` I wonder why you have that code. What would be the value of s after this statement? You could Toast s already there to see. You better just change that to `String s = "";`

Comment: Further you have terrible complex read code. Have a look at `readLine()`.

Comment: @greenapps sorry, yes it can print out Toast a, but link was not able to connect, did you have any ideas on this?

Comment: I already gave you hints. Further you could Toast `"http://"+a+"/try.php"`. Please do and report. Answer my question about valueOf().

Comment: @greenapps, hi, yes i get "http://127.168.43.184/try.php"

Comment: Then you have written a strange post to begin with. You could have left out that txt file and reading it of course. You just could have started with that url. `String url = "http://127.168.43.184/try.php";`. The subject does not make sense.